# Traps are not listened by Manager in snmp4j

Tags: java, scala, akka, snmp4j

Traps are coming from Agent but Manager is not listening the traps.I write a Agent code and send traps on localhost.I tried with MibBrowser traps are received from agent but manager is not listening.

I'm doing it in Scala, on java same code is working.

Agent Code

```
case class SnmpDevice(host: String, port: Int, readCommunity: String, writeCommunity: String)

class NETrapSender {
  def createCommunityTarget(snmpDevice: SnmpDevice): CommunityTarget = {
  try {
    var comtarget: CommunityTarget = null
    if (snmpDevice != null && snmpDevice.host != null && snmpDevice.port > 0 && snmpDevice.readCommunity != null) {
      comtarget = new CommunityTarget()
      comtarget.setCommunity(new OctetString(snmpDevice.readCommunity))
      comtarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c)
      comtarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress(snmpDevice.host + "/" + snmpDevice.port))
      comtarget.setRetries(2)
      comtarget.setTimeout(5000)
      comtarget
    }
    comtarget
} catch {
  case e: Exception =>
    e.printStackTrace()
    throw e
  }
```

}

```
def createPDU(trapOid: String): PDU = {
  var pdu: PDU = new PDU
  try {
  pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysUpTime, new OctetString(new Date().toString())));
  pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID, new OID(trapOid)));
  pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapAddress, new IpAddress("127.0.0.1")));
  pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(trapOid), new OctetString("Major")));

  //pdu.setType(PDU.INFORM) // Inform type request
  pdu.setType(PDU.NOTIFICATION)
  pdu
} catch {
  case e: Exception =>
    e.printStackTrace()
    throw e
 }
```

}

```
def sendTrap(snmpDevice: SnmpDevice, trapOid: String) {
 val udptransportMapping = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping()
 udptransportMapping.listen()
 val snmp = new Snmp(udptransportMapping)

 val target = createCommunityTarget(snmpDevice)
 val pdu = createPDU(trapOid)
 println(" Sending V2 Trap to " + snmpDevice.host + " on Port " + snmpDevice.port);

val response = snmp.inform(pdu, target)
 println(" repsonse event::" + response.getResponse)
 snmp.close
 //for INFROM
 /*val responseEvent: ResponseEvent = snmp.inform(pdu, target)
 println(" repsonse event::" + responseEvent.getResponse)*/
```

}
 }

```
object NETrapSender extends App{
   val trapSenderObj = new NETrapSender
   val device = SnmpDevice("127.0.0.1", 2222, "public", "private")
   val trapOID = "1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1" //coldStart 
   trapSenderObj.sendTrap(device, trapOID)
}
```

Listner (Manager) code:

```
class TrapListener(snmpDevice: SnmpDevice) extends Thread {
 val lock: AnyRef = new AnyRef

 override def run(): Unit = {
  listen()
}

def listen(){
  lock.synchronized {
    val address = new UdpAddress(snmpDevice.host + "/" + snmpDevice.port)
    val transport: DefaultUdpTransportMapping = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
    transport.listen()
    val msDispatcher: MessageDispatcher = new MessageDispatcherImpl
    msDispatcher.addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv2c)

    SecurityProtocols.getInstance.addDefaultProtocols()
    SecurityProtocols.getInstance.addPrivacyProtocol(new Priv3DES)
    val snmp: Snmp = new Snmp(msDispatcher, transport);
    println(" before processing")
    val trapPrinter = new CommandResponder() {
     override def processPdu(e: CommandResponderEvent) {
      println("WONN")
      lock.synchronized {
        println("inside process pdu")
        val command = e.getPDU();
        if (command != null) {
          System.out.println("command:: " + command.toString());
        }
      }
    }
  };
  snmp.addCommandResponder(trapPrinter);
  println(" listening on ..." + snmpDevice.host)
  lock.wait(1000 * 60 *1)
 }
```

}

```
object TrapListner extends App {
 val snmpDevice = SnmpDevice("127.0.0.1", 2222, "public", "private")
new TrapListener(snmpDevice).start()
val trapOID = "1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.1" //coldStart
new NETrapSender().sendTrap(snmpDevice, trapOID)
```

}

Agent is sending traps properly, I've tested on mibBrowser. But Manager is not able to receive traps.Seems to some issue with Scala wait,synchronized. Tried the same on java working properly.

Is there any other approach in scala we can use.i tried with Future,Blocking block but didn't get any result.

Comment: What's the output of that logging?

Comment: @Paul processPdu(e: CommandResponderEvent) method is never being called i.e traps are listened by Manager!

Comment: What happens if you remove the synchronized stuff? (I know not a good idea generally, but might help troubleshoot)